# Android resource linking failed-imageview

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, imageview, android-glide

[image: IMAGEVIEW]
I try to display images from api, using glide library but I do get error in activity_main.xml, more precise in ImageView. I have done things like clean project, rebuild project, Invalidate and restart etc but the error is still there. Any suggestions?

[image: ERRORLOG]

Comment: welcome! please try to use code snippets rather than attaching images, this makes it easier for others to easily search for similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the line

```
 app:layout_conta.....@id/coinSymbol
```

and

```
android:id=...
```

You are trying to constrain your layout with itself, which is causing the error. Please remove the first line and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you set the constraint of the imageview to itself (using the same id) in line:

> app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/coinSymbol"

this can and will cause the resource linking error.

Comment: hi i have below codes about ImageView that show error: "Android resource linking failed"